# Sync Framework COM class error

Tags: c#, microsoft-sync-framework

I have a problem that is giving me dizzy for several days.
I have a program for desktop develop in **C#** and WPF that needs many components to function. I will explain:

The system works in disconnected scenarios, for that you need a local database (SQL Server Express); there is a central server where all information is gathered all computers, to achieve synchronization, the program requires Sync Framework.

When the system is first installed, it is required that there is an instance of SQL Server Express previously installed, then the system automatically creates the database and start the synchronization process.
Provisioning runs smoothly, in fact, all tables are created in the new database, but when trying to run data synchronization, gives the following error:

> Could not retrieve the COM class factory for component with CLSID
>   {EC413D66-6221-4EBB-AC55-4900FB321011} due to the following error:
>   80040154 Class not registered (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80040154
>   (REGDB_E_CLASSNOTREG))."}

The error occurs in the following line:

```
// Execute the synchronization process
SyncOperationStatistics syncStats = syncOrchestrator.Synchronize();
```

---

I had to install on one of the computers on which the system would be installed and what I did was install a package NuGet called **Microsoft.SyncFramework** *by Darrel Tunnell*. While installed in the project, on the computer **Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 Core Components (x86) ENU** was installed.

I have some questions:

1. Is it possible to correct that error from the solution without
   having to install another component on the machine where the system
   is installed?
2. If this is not possible, how I can include the component in the system
   installer? I use Inno Setup for that.

Just to clarify a few points:

- The references of the components are x86
- The target platform is configured in the project x86

I thank you very much for your time and help.

Comment: Have you tried installing the redistributables on the machine in question? https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19502

Comment: Greatly I want to avoid having to install components on the computer on which the system will be installed. That was the package that was installed when I did from NuGet

Comment: Also, in the Properties page, go to Build -> Platform target and choose x86 or x64 specifically (depends if your machine is 64 bit or not)

Comment: @silkfire The computer on which I am developing the system is x64, but in which the program will be installed, the system is x86, for this reason the project was compiled on x86.

Comment: So your question is basically: How do you get an application dependent on Microsoft Sync Framework running without installing Microsoft Sync Framework 2.1 Core Components, but only the NuGet package?

Comment: Or do you mean that NuGet installs the redistributables on the developer machine but not on the machine where the application is going to be run? Might be impossible without the redistributables...

Comment: I think I'm confused. Although the program has references to Syn Framework, it is necessary on the computer where it will be installed, it is also installed the package?

Comment: It seems like that, yes. Do you have limitations on the machine where it's going to be run?

Comment: The problem is rather when installing the program on those machines. So how do I install the package sync framework on par with the system?

Comment: I'm sorry, why are you having difficulties installing Sync Framework on said machine?

Comment: The system will be installed on machines outside the city, on computers set to the same system characteristics. Computers are new and just want to install the system and be restricted for everything else.